# How can I compare two strings and count the number of similar characters?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a JavaScript function which compares two strings and return the number of similar occurrences. But my function is considering duplicates as well.

For example, two words 'state' and 'tall'. Ideally it should return a count of two but it is returning three considering two duplicate t's in 'state'.

Code:

```
for (I = 0; I < str1.length; I++) {
    for (j = 0; j < str2.length; j++). {
        if (str1[I] === str2[j]) {
            count++
        }
    }
}) return count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is ES5 solution:

```js
function solution(str1, str2) {
    var count = 0;
    var find = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
        find = str2.indexOf(str1.charAt(i));
        if (find > -1) {
          count++;
          str2 = str2.substr(0, find) + str2.substr(find + 1);
        }
    }
    return count;
};

console.log(solution('state', 'tall'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const countSimilarities = (s1, s2) =>
  s1
    .split("")
    .map((char1) => s2.split("").find((char2) => char1 === char2))
    .reduce((acc, c) => (c ? acc + 1 : acc), 0);
```

Comment: thank you.. but could you please advice on how to work it out without using map

Comment: Please check Arthur Sidorenko the ES5 answer

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Could probably be optimized a bit beyond this, but this is a fairly simple version of a function to make this check.

```js
function matchingLettersCount(s1, s2) {
  const letters1 = [...new Set(s1.split(''))];
  const letters2 = [...new Set(s2.split(''))];
  return letters1.filter(x => letters2.includes(x)).length;
}

console.log(matchingLettersCount('state', 'tall'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace "gi" with "g" if you want it to be case sensitive.

```js
function stringsCompare ( string , subString ) {
    let count = 0;
    string.replace(new RegExp(subString, "gi"), () => count++ )
    return count;
}

//=========== test examples =================

console.log(stringsCompare("this is a string a b c", "a")) ; // 2 occurances
console.log(stringsCompare("foofoofoo", "foo")) ;            // 3 occurances
console.log(stringsCompare("aaaaaaaaa", "aa")) ;             // 4 occurrences mmmm
```